# Upgrade cassandra cql spec

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

Is there any way to upgrade cassandra cql spec version from 3.1.1 to 3.1.4 without upgrading cassandra itself? 
We are using cassandra version 2.0.9 and haven't found any documentation related to this issue.

Comment: The short answer is don't. If you want to pull cqlsh from a newer verson of C* you'll probably see stack traces.

Comment: Roling upgrades are not too painful though: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/dseUpgradeProcedure_t.html

Comment: I've done that before while building patches for cqlsh.  I don't recommend it unless A) you really understand cqlsh, B) your Python is pretty good and C) you are working in an environment that you can afford to mess up, blow-away, rebuild, and try again, ad infinitum.  Needless to say, there isn't any documentation on it since you really aren't meant to be doing that.