# cassandra version Error

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Hi anyone instruct me which version of cassandra should I use to run cqlsh-3.4.3, So that i will be able to run GROUP BY queries.

Currently My environment is

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4]
```

Error on trying   bin/cqlsh --cqlversion=3.4.3

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.4.3' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.2']",)})
```

Please Suggest.Thanks.

Same Error while tried with cassandra 3.7 Also.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to force cqlsh to use a specific cql version using the [option](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html)

--cqlversion="#.#.#"

[example](https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/568fce1c62ea3cca0797c93f0dfae2dd): cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042 --cqlversion="3.2.0" (in your case: 3.4.2)

example of mine:

```
me@XXX:~$ cqlsh <cassandra_ip>
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {<cassandra_ip>: ProtocolError("cql_version '3.4.2' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.3.1']",)})
me@XXX:~$ cqlsh <cassandra_ip> --cqlversion="3.3.1"
Connected to UAT Analytics Cluster at <cassandra_ip>:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

**UPDATE**

(1) `group by` will be supported in [CQL 3.4.3](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/changes.html#id1) and Cassandra [3.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707).

(2) It is [not recommended to upgrade CQL spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386341/upgrade-cassandra-cql-spec) for Cassandra of specific version. OR it is impossible to upgrade CQL spec version for one Cassandra version ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151079/cassandra-3-9-and-cql-spec-version/41151536#41151536)).

(3) In order to use `group by`, you should upgrade cassandra to 3.10, OR user defined functions, OR change your table design...

Comment: I am able to run --cqlversion="3.4.2", BUt this does not suffice my need of "RUNNING GROUP BY queries". As per documentation on (Cassandra WebSite), Groupby query is supported from  --cqlversion="3.4.3". Mark it's 3.4.3... But do u know any cassandra version which supports it. I tried with latest stable version I:e: 3.9 and when tried  bin/cqlsh localhostIP --cqlversion=3.4.3 , I faced some error. SO i asked the question.

Comment: You modified your question?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707, I guess `group by` will be supported in Cassandra 3.10. I will double check.

Comment: @LoneRanger I guess `group by` will be supported in Cassandra 3.10 and cql 3.4.3 (as for your comments). So, the point is that your current cassandra database cannot support `group by`. I will double check.

Comment: @LoneRange Sorry for that, I am trying to give more accurate details. But there are several issues: 1, your cassandra server supports 3.4.2, so you cannot use `--cqlversion=3.4.3`; 2, I am not sure whether cassandra 3.9 supports cql version 3.4.3, and how to upgrade it to use 3.4.3; i am trying to help.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your support. Do you have any other storage-system in your mind/experience like cassandra where i can run some aggregation query faster. Not (Spark, or hadoop-Hive-MongoDb, For some reason i am not using these options)??  Because for 3.10 to release, it seems we need to wait for another couple of weeks or Month.

Comment: @LoneRanger May this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342176/max-distinct-and-group-by-in-cassandra help.